# Skip back activity without reloading it and then go back to it

Tags: android

Activity A calls me Activity B and C.

```
    Intent intent_mapa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
    intent_mapa.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent_mapa);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then C calls me to Activity D.

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Activity D then calls me Activity B without reloading the WebView, Activity B has a WebView and I do not want the url to be reloaded.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
```

When I give back to Activity D I call Activity C without closing D, and if I want to reopen Activity D I should not refresh Activity D.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: as long as you don't `finish` the activities, and make sure to override `onBackPressed` to handle your navigation yourself, it should work.

Comment: The problem is that I open Activity B at least 2 times because it is called from Activity A and Activity D.

How to make it so it is called from different Activity I open only once ????

Answer (score 0):

The way, Android 'opens' Activities is (as you can see in you code) via Intents. So what you actually do with startActivity(Intent...) is, you tell Android you have the intent to run the specified Activity. Now it depends on the flags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_...) how Android handles that intent of yours. Also see the official documentation regarding [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).